# In Semantic UI, deal with "Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate"

Tags: forms, validation, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css, error-messages-for

**I'm using Semantic-UI (with Codeigniter, no React or anything beyond common use) to validate a form.** 
**This is the semantic UI init code:**

```
$form.form({
   on: "submit",
   fields: fieldsToValidate,
   inline: true
});
```

*I want the errors messages to show in the correct input field and I already included the `semantic.min.js` and `semantic.min.css` files* (in other similar questions I found that this may be the reason for my problem but it's not), *but every time I submit the form I get this error:*

> Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. 
>   Use silent setting to surpress this warning in production. scale in

I cannot make sense of this error, any kind of suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you all!

**All Semantic-Ui files imported.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/js/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css') }}" />
<script src="{{ asset('/js/semantic-ui/semantic.min.js') }}"></script>
```

*Error message on submit:*

> Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. 
>   Use silent setting to surpress this warning in production. scale in